# First glword of the next page alignment to a page number

Tags: xetex, expex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{fwlw}
\makeatletter
\def\ps@foo{\def\@oddfoot{\footnotesize\centering\hfil\thepage\hfil\hbox to 0pt{\hss\usebox\NextWordBox}}\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\lingset{glbreaking}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{foo}
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl

\leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{aaa}\hbox{bbb}\hbox{ccc}}
\leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{ddd}\hbox{eee}\hbox{fff}}
\leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{ggg}\hbox{hhh}\hbox{jjj}}

\vspace{5mm}

\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\begingl
\gla First document. This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included.//
\glb document This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First.//
\glc This is a simple example, with no extra parameters or packages included First document.//
\endgl
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that expex glword in a footnote does not allign to a page number there with its glc word, as it should, like with vbox on the second page.